# I want to edit the search function

Tags: search

I'm changing some parts of WordPress, like adding posts or comments, to use procedures in the database instead of using inline database calls to see if the performance enhances. I've been looking the search function now, but I can't find the code for it, the select string more importantly.

Anyone who can help me locate where the code for the search function is (like searching for posts or comments not the archive)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically everything query-related is in [`wp-includes/query.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/query.php). Search for the `parse_search` function in that file and the [`posts_search`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_search) and `posts_search_orderby` filters.

Comment: Could you maybe help me understand what    $search .= "{$searchand}(($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') OR ($wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}'))";
this does?